# How to recast float to integer for selected column numbers in Hive?

Tags: python, hive, casting, floating-point, integer

A number of columns containing what appeared to be 0/1 integer values in my Hive table are rewritten as 0.0 or 1.0 float values after pulling the table into a Python data frame. Therefore what I thought were 1 byte integer fields are eating up more memory as float variables.

Is there a way to select multiple fields by column # in a Hive table and recast the columns from float to integer?

Comment: Are those columns being float in Hive's table or int? How do you read Hive's table to Python dataframe, by means of spark or somehow else?

Comment: @serge_k The columns I'd like to recast are type *double*. I read tables into Python using the connect function (hive_conn = connect(host=..., port=..., auth_mechanism=..., kerberos_service_name=...)) followed by the read_sql function (df = pd.read_sql('''select * from < table name >"", hive_conn)).

Comment: @serge_k Hmm, looks like it's not possible to select a range or group of column numbers in Hive. I was able to recast from double to int, but had to use list all the column nams in Hive, then copy & paste into Excel and create the select cast(x1 as int), cast(x2 as int) ..... from data_table; statement.